# How to create a new text file in C?

Tags: c, text-files

I am creating a program which reads data from one text file and changes it size to upper or lower case and then stores that data in a new file. I have searched the internet, but I can't find how to create a new text file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

        FILE *fp = NULL;

        fp = fopen("textFile.txt" ,"a");

        char choice;

        if (fp != NULL) {

                printf("Change Case \n");
                printf("============\n");
                printf("Case (U for upper, L for lower) : ");
                scanf(" %c", &choice);
                printf("Name of the original file : textFile.txt \n");
                printf("Name of the updated file : newFile.txt \n");
```

I know this is incomplete, but I can't figure out how to crate a new text file!

Comment: `a` is for "append". if the file exists, it'll be appended to. you probably want `w`, for write - if the file exists, it'll be truncated and you start fresh.

Comment: Marc is correct, also be sure to close at the end if you don't want unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: fopen creates the file if you open a new file for writing see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840629/create-a-file-if-one-doesnt-exist-c

Answer (score 12):

```cpp
fp = fopen("textFile.txt" ,"a");
```

This is a correct way to create a text file. The issue is with your `printf` statements. What you want instead is:

```cpp
fprintf(fp, "Change Case \n");
...
```

Comment: (You should check that `fp != NULL`, but you already do) ; Don't forget to call `fclose(fp);` at end. You might want to sometimes call `fflush`

Comment: The "at" mode for `fopen()` is not part of **7.21.5.3 The `fopen` function** in the C standard.  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Comment: What does the fprintf(fp, "change case \n"); do? Thanks

Comment: @HassenFatima, it writes "change case" into a file that handle `fp` points to. Unlike regular `printf`, that writes into stdout.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define FILE_NAME "text.txt"

int main()
{
    FILE* file_ptr = fopen(FILE_NAME, "w");
    fclose(file_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find it quite strange there isn't a system call API for explicitly creating a new file. A concise version of the above answers is:

```
fclose(fopen("text.txt", "a"));
```

Comment: This ignores errors.